# send data from servlet java to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, refresh

I'm doing a project in java in which I implemented a chat, everything works perfectly only when I receive messages I can not print the web page.
In my Servlet I have a callback method that is invoked when messages arrive, in fact if you see mold them in the console, but if you are sending them to the jsp using the RequestDispatcher can not get them to see.

I would like to know if there is a system that the jsp page listens for a callback method in the servlet?

Obviously, this system should not be constantly invoke the class I have something absurd like that.

So that I can print the messages I receive.

---

This is my code I put a comment where I should print eventually find in jsp page, or do a redirect by passing parameters post or get

```
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    String strJid = (String) request.getParameter("jid");
    String strMessage = (String) request.getParameter("textMessage");


    Connection connection = (Connection)getServletContext().getAttribute("classConnection");

    ChatManager chatManager = connection.getChatManager();
    Chat newChat = chatManager.createChat(strJid, new MessageListener(){


        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message){

     //from here I have to print the message.getBody () in jsp page,
    //how can I do? I'm happy also reload the page and pass as a parameter to get or post

        }
    });

    try{
        newChat.sendMessage(strMessage);
    }
    catch(XMPPException e){
        System.out.println("Errore invio messaggio");
    }


}
```

Comment: Can't understand clearly what you are looking for, please update your question with some code and may be step-by-step explanation of what you are trying to do and where you are stuck. Thanks

Comment: I'm stuck to the point that when the servlet receives messages via the callback method, I can not print them in jsp page

Answer (score 0):

To implement a callback method in your servlet to receive chat messages is the wrong approach. A servlet will be called once for a browser request, creates the HTML page and send it back to the browser. After that there is no such kind of a connection between the servlet and the web page.

In traditional web programming all communication between browser and server is intiated by the client. There is no way for the server to send a message to the client. Workarounds are long polling requests.

But nowadays you can use [Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). There are several frameworks supporting Websockets both for client and server side. One of them is [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere#readme). Their [tutorial](http://async-io.org/tutorial.html) is a chat application.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it is not cross-browser

Comment: Hm, according to Atmosphere's Supported WebServers and Browsers site https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Supported-WebServers-and-Browsers all major web browsers are supported. With old browser versions you can at least use long polling as a fallback. But Atmosphere was only an example. There are several other Websocket frameworks out there. Most of them support some kind of fallback mechanism if Websockets aren't directly supported. But nothing prevents you to use the bare Websocket API on your own.

Comment: you can call a javascript function from a java servlet.
If so, how can you do?

Comment: The servlet code runs on server side while your JavaScript function resides on the client (the browser). So the servlet cannot directly call the JavaScript function. You can store messages on server side and deliver them the next time the client does a request or you can use some kind of push technology like websockets to send a message directly to the client (which may call your JavaScript function). But that is beyond the capabilities of a simple servlet.